# Could not render "example'' is undefined

Tags: yaml, jinja2, dbt

Hello I created a macro in
example_macro.sql
This is the example_macro.sql:

```
{% macro example_macro() -%}
{% set example_set%}
example_team:
    team: 'Sales'
    team2: 'tec'
{% endset %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then I have a SQL Model where I executed this:

```
--{{ fromyaml(global_variables())['responsible_team']['sal'] }}
```

and this is working fine
in a .yml file in the same directory when I try to execute it I'm getting this error:

> Could not render '{{
> fromyaml(example_m,acro())['example_team']['team'] }}':
> 'example_macro' is undefined

is there any alternative way I can do it in a .yml file? or How does Jinja handle it? I tried many things but I can not figure out any workaround...

Comment: There seems to be a _macros_ folder for that, see the example at https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros#macros and https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/macro-paths